# number rows in table and views without select

Tags: sql-server, metadata

I want to know for table and view the number rows will be selected by

```
select *from [name_table_or_view]
```

**without** select or exec but only by meta-data
can you help me,please
thank you
shelli g.

Comment: To get the number of rows, you should be using `select count(*) from t`.

Comment: You can get a non-transactional count of rows in a table from the DMVs but not from a view (unless it's indexed).

Comment: Gurwinder Singh,you help me very much but it only for tables do you know how to do it for views too, my thank you shelli

Comment: yes I heard again that I can't count rows for views by meta data but maybe anyone know some thing about How can I do it hhowever